# Correctly routing interface 2 to interface 1 on Windows to give Internet Access to other hosts

Tags: windows, networking, routing, vmware, routing-table

I have the situation like in the picture:[network scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vJh3.png)
[image]

I would like to let the centos vm to access Internet.
What's the correct command I should enter into the Windows'shell?
I already enabled IPRouting on regedit.exe.
I put here two routing tables, one after my configuration and one after enabling Windows Internet Sharing.
It seems like the same thing, but the first does not work, the second does.

```
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.40.2   192.168.40.129    266
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
          192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.2.129    266
        192.168.2.129  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.129    266
        192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.129    266
         192.168.40.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
       192.168.40.129  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
       192.168.40.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.2.129    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.129    266
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.40.2  Default
    ===========================================================================
    ===========================================================================

    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.40.2   192.168.40.129    266
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
         192.168.40.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
       192.168.40.129  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
       192.168.40.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
        192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    266
        192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    266
      192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.40.129    266
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    266
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.40.2  Default 
    ===========================================================================
```

Comment: Enable ICS on VM1(eth1) simply. Maybe Win7 would ask to alter eth2 subnet to 192.168.0.0/24 - do it, and then set VM2 to DHCP.

Comment: I updated the question after following your advice.